# Losing value of static variable declared in Global.asax and initialized in onstart event of webrole

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have declared a static string "drivePath" in Gloabal.asax.cs. In Onstart event of webrole I am assigning a value to it. I am accessing this value on my web page but it shows as if the variable is just declared. The value I get for the My code is as follows

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public static string drivePath = string.Empty;
```

**WebRole.cs**

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
    MountAzureDrive();
    Global.drivePath = WebRole.drivePath;
    return base.OnStart();
}
```

I am assigning value to WebRole.drivePath in "MountAzureDrive()" function.

On Web Page

On the web page in some function I am accessing the drivePath as "Global.drivePath" and I am getting value as string.Empty.

My question is Why is not preserving the value of drive path? What do I have to do, if I want to preserve the value of drivepath and get it?

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnStart (Role) is in another process than your web page (pages, Global.asax ..). At least when using [Full IIS mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx).

Comment: So how shall I get the drivePath after mounting the drive in the OnStart event? Because I am assigning the value to drivePath in Onstart  event as you can see to access it through out the life time of web application. My all operations are performed on the same drivePath.

Comment: Have you looked at calling http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive.getmounteddrives.aspx from Global.asax ? Or do you have multiple drives and need to know which one?

Comment: You mean I have to call MountAzureDrive() function in Application_Start of Global.asax instead of Onstart of WebRole?

Comment: Mounting it in OnStart is probably a good idea if is a necessary prerequisite for your web role to work properly. You could call CloudDrive.GetMountedDrives in Global.Application_Start and put the drive letter into the static field for the IIS process.
If you decide on mounting it from Global.asax you would need to check if it isn't already there because of (possible) multiple IIS app pool/worker processes.

Comment: I implemented the MountAzureDrive() method in Application_Start event of Global.asax instead of WebRole onstart but still I am getting string.Empty value in drivePath on web page

Comment: Are you seeing this in the emulator? are there multiple instances of your application? Is the mounting code really executed? Have you tried restarting the emulator (to avoid static code not being executed as expected).

Comment: Yes you were right!! I need to restart the emulator so I did. I also deleted my global.asax file and created new one and rewritten the code.

Answer (score 2):

The code running in the WebRole is not the same process as your web application (Global.asax.cs). What you could do is the following:

1. WebRole: Mount the drive
2. WebRole: Store the drive letter as an environment variable
3. Global.asax.cs: Read the drive letter from the environment variable.
4. ...

[image]

Follow this article for more information: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81413/Windows-Azure-Drives-Part-1-Configure-and-Mounting

Sandrino